# Please help me to run latex in mac

Tags: miktex, texstudio, mac

When I run my file then I get this error message :

```
Process started: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "Bab7TeknikIntegrasi".tex        
log4cxx: setFile(/Users/mukhammadsolikhin/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log,true) 
call failed. log4cxx: IO Exception : status code = 13        
log4cxx: No output stream or file set for the appender named [RollingLogFile].

Sorry, but /usr/local/bin/pdflatex did not succeed. The log file 
hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
/Users/mukhammadsolikhin/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/miktex/log/pdflatex.log   
Process exited with error(s)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about not only the error messages you're getting but also about what you're trying to achieve. E.g., is my interpretation that you tried to install MikTeK on a MacOS system correct? If so, please tell us which steps you took and which instructions you executed.

Comment: Only a few people worldwide uses MiKTeX on macOS. Nearly all use MacTeX: https://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: I agree just install mactex. It is the easiest latex to install. Just remember to update it afterwards

Comment: Also remove MikTeX since it seems to put binaries in `/user/local/bin` directly and they will be found before the ones for TeX Live installed by MacTeX.